# how to pass data to jquery cycle onBefore function

Tags: jquery, cycle, jquery-cycle

I'm trying to get data from either the 'curr' or 'next' object available in jquery cycle's onBefore function so I can pass it to a PHP script with ajax to populate opts.addSlide();

Ideally i'd like to be use the data() attribute but i'm struggling even to use .attr()

In the documentation, this works:

```
var currentImageNum = parseInt(next.src.match(/beach(\d)/)[1]);
```

and i've seen this working

```
var tag = next.tagName.toLowerCase();
```

so why can't I use this or something similar

```
var mydata = next.attr('id');
```

to get the ID of the slide

the error I get is Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'attr'

Comment: Thanks both of you, it was a beginner's mistake! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `next` is a DOM element you should first convert it into jQuery object and then you can call jQuery apis on it. Try this

`$(next).attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

`next` is probably a DOMElement. Wrap it in jquery:

`$(next).attr('id')` or just do `next.id`

`.src` is a property of elements like `img` and `tagName` is a property of all DOM elements, so I assume `next` is an `img`.